# Will a Dell Inspiron 1545 model be able to run Ubuntu 20.04 successfully purely for self hosted cloud storage?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dell, cloud

Ive installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell inspiron 1545 model (2010), purely for use as self hosted cloud storage server, but Ive been struggling to get the wifi to work ( I also tried installing virtualbox on it, but because my chip does not support virtualization i cannot use ubuntu on virtual box). I just want to know if ubuntu 20.04 will be able to run successfully on my older dell computer or am I wasting my time trying to set it up ? So far I cannot even pick up the wifi signal with the wifi router a meter away (but it does pick up my neighbor’s wifi for some reason). Im very new to ubuntu and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: *yes*.

As long as you have 4GiB RAM or more and a *not-potato* CPU, you should be okay as long as you don't try and use it as a massive server. If there is only a few clients connecting to it from time to time and not a massive workload, then yes -  especially as a storage server, it ideally would be fine.

Not sure about the WiFi thing though, id suggest using ethernet if you can.

Edit: Ubuntu says the minimum specs are:

```
2 GHz dual core processor.
4 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution.
```

I looked up your laptop specs and found:

```
Processor: INTEL CORE 2 DUO CPU P7450.
Clock Speed: 2.13GHZ.
RAM: 4GB DDR2.
Hard Drive: 500GB.
```

If they are similar if not better, then yes you can.